# Mouseover on map areas is not fire on webkit (safari, chrome), css mistake?

Tags: jquery, css

I am making a game map editor using jquery

http://www.trouverunebabysitter.fr/messages/map

Everything works fine on mozilla but not on safari. The area mouseover is not fire... I think it's a css problem but i don't know what i did wrong.

If anyone can help me. (I think the best way is to use firebug to see my css/html....)

Thank a lot

Comment: Can you give us more info? The mouseover on which element? P.S. Neat project!

Comment: The mouseover the <area> elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that your map tag have the same **id** and **name**. It seems that Firefox and IE don't require the name attribute unlike Chrome and Safari.

```
<map id="mySuperID" name="mySuperID">...</map>
```

Comment: Yes sorry, i forgot to write my solution but you right, i forgot the name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to binding your mouseover event to `.map-areas-div` elements instead of `<area>`
? In webkit, the user-agent stylesheet sets `<area>` elements to `display:none;`, which would cause mouseover events to not work.

Comment: I really need to have event on <area> because to have all square of my grid available, i need to put it on the front.

Comment: What about forcing `area { display: block !important; }`? Maybe that'd work?

Comment: You don't have an other idea?

Comment: I found my error :( I forgot to add name="#my_id" to the <map> tag :) Thank you for help